# Long type equality

Tags: .net

How is the following possible?

[image]

We have two longs with equal vlaues but they are not equal...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compile-time type of the expression is `object`, not `long`. Therefore `==` is comparing the *references*. It's like this:

```
object x = 9L;
object y = 9L;
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // false
Console.WriteLine(x.Equals(y)); // true
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(x, y)); // true; avoids NullReferenceException
```

You have two distinct objects, both being "boxes" for the long values. `==` on `object` only compares whether the references refer to the exact same object. `Equals` compares the objects with each other for *value* equality, so will return true.

If the compile-time types of the two expressions were `long`, `==` would compare them *as long values* and that would be fine.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, I'd say you are comparing two objects, and not two integers. The objects are not pointing to the same memory address, thus are not equal.
If you do a `Convert.ToInt64(otherRouteValue) == Convert.ToInt64(RouteKeyValue.Value)` you should get the desired result

Answer (score 2):

`==` compares the objects (return true if there are the same objects, same references).

To evaluate an equality between object values, use `obj.Equals(obj)` method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47.aspx

In your case : `routeKeyValue.Value.Equals(otherRouteKeyValue);`

Answer (score 1):

Because it are `object`s. You could use .Equals, or declare them as being `long`.